# What is the regex for detecting \n in a string? Here \ and n are stored in two different cells of a string

Tags: android, regex, special-characters

**Case 1:** I am reading a line from a file. Ex: `"There is an error. \n Do you want to continue?"`
**Problem:** When I am displaying this in a Dialog in android, I am seeing the `\n` in the display and `"Do you want to continue?"` is not being shown in the new line.
When debugging, I observed that `\` and `n` are stored in separate cells (of the string).

**Case 2:** On the other hand, instead of reading from file, if define the above string in code base, then `\n` seems to be stored in a single cell.  I don't see `\n` and I see `"Do you want to continue?"` in new line.

**Regarding Case 1:** What I am trying to do now is to remove `\` and `n` from the string and add new line.

```
string = string.replace("regex", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

What would be the regex to detect `\` and `n` in this case?

Comment: What have you tried? If it's being interpreted literally, I think `\n` or maybe `\\n` should do the trick. So that's `string = string.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are seeing the below as output:

```
There is an error. \n Do you want to continue?
```

The following should work, use double escapes to match a literal.

```
String s = "There is an error. \\n Do you want to continue?";
s = s.replace("\\n", "\n");
System.out.println(s);
// There is an error. 
//  Do you want to continue?
```

OR

```
String s = "There is an error. \\n Do you want to continue?";
s = s.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
System.out.println(s);
// There is an error. 
//  Do you want to continue?
```

Answer (score 3):

You should escape the backslash character to specify a literal backslash.  So something like the following should work:

```
String s = "There is an error. \\n Do you want to continue?";
s = s.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator");
System.out.println(s);
```